# JavaScript DOM Background Opacity

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am using something similar to the following code: (in JavaScript Interface Android)

```
node.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
node.style.opacity = 0.5;
```

but i don't want result.
i only want to apply a transparent background color.

Comment: Use `rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use [rgba](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#rgba())

```js
var node = document.getElementById('d2');
node.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .5)";
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
}
#d1 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<br />
<div id="d2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
node.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .5)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the backgroundColor in rgb and there to set the opacity like this

```
node.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
```